Access violation error when lib try to create file
I created logger lib, and its works fine in test projects. But in my .dll project when I use create file method, it throws runtime access violation error in open method fstream.h file.
basic_filebuf* open(const char* _Filename, ios_base::openmode _Mode, int _Prot = ios_base::_Default_open_prot) {
        // _Prot is an extension
        if (_Myfile) {
            return nullptr;
        }

        const auto _File = _Fiopen(_Filename, _Mode, _Prot);
        if (!_File) {
            return nullptr; // open failed
        }

        _Init(_File, _Openfl);
        _Initcvt(_STD use_facet<_Cvt>(_Mysb::getloc()));
        return this; // open succeeded
    }

Exception thrown at 0x00007FFCD48D8578 (msvcp140d.dll) in Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.
    `_Initcvt(_STD use_facet<_Cvt>(_Mysb::getloc())); -> code part where exception throws

`
If I create ofstream object in dll everything works fine, but it doesnt work if I use lib.
    TLogManager::GetLogManager()->create("file.txt");
here is code where I run create method
#ifndef TLOGMANAGER_H_INCLUDED
#define TLOGMANAGER_H_INCLUDED

//------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <exception>

#ifndef THROW_EXCEPTION
#define THROW_EXCEPTION(ErrorNum, ErrorDesc) throw TException(ErrorNum, ErrorDesc, __FILE__, __LINE__ );
#endif

//------------------------------------------------------------------------

//Custom exception class

class TException : public std::exception
{
private:
protected:
public:
    int m_ErrorNumber;
    std::string m_ErrorDesc;
    std::string m_SrcFileName;
    int m_LineNumber;
    std::string m_ErrText;

    // Override std::exception::what
    const char* what();

    TException(int ErrorNumber, std::string ErrorDesc, std::string SrcFileName, int LineNumber);
    ~TException() throw() {}
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------

//Singleton Logging Object

class TLogManager
{
public:
    static TLogManager* GetLogManager();

protected:
    TLogManager();
    virtual ~TLogManager() {}
    static TLogManager m_LogManager;

public:
    std::stringstream m_LogBuffer;
    void create(std::string Filename);
    void flush();
    void close();
    void logException(TException e);
    std::string getTimeString();
    std::ofstream m_LogFile;
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------

#endif // TLOGMANAGER_H_INCLUDED



void TLogManager::create(std::string Filename)
{
    m_LogFile.open(Filename.c_str());
}

here is my method implementation in lib
I tried creating this logic in dll, everything works, it doesnt want to work with lib. I tried to search, but hot nothing.

I checked, this problens occurs only in dll files,  not in exe

Are you mixing debug and release DLLs?

I found that its probably because _Plocale* doesnt initialized (in exe its initialized)

@Botje no, everything ok with that. Its because _Plocale* doesnt initialize and I dont know why
